# MongoDB php7 driver installation

Tags: mongodb, apache2, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04, pecl

I'm working on an Ubuntu 16 server and I can't seem to get the mongodb driver for php 7 to work. I installed it successfully on my xampp on my windows machine but Ubuntu and php7 seemingly have vast differences.

I did try to install it via `pecl install mongodb` and used composer to put in the dependencies but it still does not work. I'm using the same php file from my windows Xampp and when I access the page it throws a 500 status code.

Could someone provide a definitive walkthrough on how to install this driver and maybe also how to revert any changes I made using composer and pecl?

Answer (score 1):

Cool even I tried with `pecl` but didn't work as expected. It work with `pecl7` Also, I received this warning along with error, `WARNING: "pecl/mongo" is deprecated in favor of "channel:///mongodb" pecl/mongo requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 5.99.99), installed version is 7.1.8`. Also, got 500 Internal server error.

Before that MongoDB php7 driver, I needed the memcache and getting phphize error that I solved using [this repo](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached). Then finally I use this low level PHP driver for MongoDB.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
$ cd mongo-php-driver
$ git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
$ /usr/bin/phpize
$ ./configure
$ make all -j 5
$ sudo make install
```

You can confirm from the output that `mongodb.so` driver is installed.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
extension=mongodb.so
```

Then only step remaining is make it available in your respective path. You can check your extensions_dir in php.ini with the following command,

```
$ php -i | grep extension_dir
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/7.0/modules => /usr/lib64/php/7.0/modules
```

And, I can verify that mongodb.so is present into the above directory. Then reload the composer and you are good to go ! Hope this helps as it work for me.